# How to Convert/Round it off

Tags: php, if-statement

I have some problem regarding converting/truncating a number.

This is the condition:

`x.35` where `x` is any decimal number. If the decimal number is less than or equal to `35` then convert the `.35` into `99` and subtract the `x` value with `1`.

Something like this:

`45.35` will become `44.99`

Any help will be much more appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a faster way that doesn't use the explode function and other unnecessary things, but here's my rendition of it.

```
    <?php
    $input = 45.35; //input, obviously
    $in2 = explode(".", $input);

    if($in2[1] <= 35) {
    $in2[1] = 99;
    }

    $output = $in2[0] . "." . $in2[1];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
http://us.php.net/floor
http://us.php.net/ceil
http://us.php.net/round

Those should help

Following up on this, here's an example.

```
$val = 45.35;  
$decimal = $val - floor($val);
if($decimal<.35) echo floor($val).".99";
```